# which post-hoc test after welch-anova

Tags: anova, letter, posthoc

i´m doing the statistical evaluation for my master´s thesis. the levene test was significant so i did the welch anova which was significant. now i tried the games-howell post hoc test but it didn´t work.

can anybody help me sending me the exact functions which i have to run in R to do the games-howell post hoc test and to get kind of a compact letter display, where it shows me which treatments are not significantly different from each other? i also wanted to ask if i did the welch anova the right way (you can find the output of R below)

here it the output which i did till now for the statistical evalutation:

`data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:`
`$ Dauer: Factor w/ 6 levels "0","2","4","6",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...`
`$ WH   : Factor w/ 5 levels "r1","r2","r3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...`
`$ TSO2 : num  107 86 98 97 88 95 93 96 96 99 ...`

`> leveneTest(TSO2~Dauer, data=TSO2R)`

### `Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
Df F value  Pr(>F)
group  5  3.3491 0.01956 *
24

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1`

`> oneway.test (TSO2 ~Dauer, data=TSO2R, var.equal = FALSE) ###Welch-ANOVA

```
One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)
```

data:  TSO2 and Dauer
F = 5.7466, num df = 5.000, denom df = 10.685, p-value = 0.00807

```
'''`
```

Thank you very much!